# A big tableview from SQL with filter - what's the most efficient way?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been trying to look into SQLite with tableviews, but Iam struggling to find a good way to work with much data - and I don't seem to find any good references online either.
I have a database of postal codes (4582 rows) and I need to join with other tables to make proper use of it. Iam not sure how to do this properly, but creating objects of all the rows would take ages on device, and the application becomes slow and unresponsive.

At first I thought I could do something like instantiate 50-100 objects and load more as you scroll, but this would backfire when they try to filter down the list, or perhaps not? I would like the user to be able to search for any row and text in the table, not just the postal codes.

Any good ideas, tips or examples on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

use 
FMDatabse. use following link for this

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Although this not solves my problem entirely, it seems like a good idea to use FMDB! I've never even heard of it, but it seems to be a far easier way then doing it all myself. I'll look into it, and update this thread as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run the code that retrieves the data on a back ground thread. Search StackOverflow or Google for Grand Central Dispatch examples.

Second, you should maybe use an NSSortDescriptor to sort your data once you have it all in an array on the main UI thread. Again, check StackOverflow for that.

Third, for searching a table view check StackOverflow, again. Read up on how to leverage the search bar and its delegate.

Lastly, the UITableView is very efficient when it comes to rendering cells or handling large amounts of data. It was built that way. I would only be concerned with the fetching of results. Your table should scroll just fine if you've implemented the table view delegate methods correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I'll need to go for a combination of these solutions. First, pulling the data from SQL with FMDB (which seems easier than regular SQLite) and then reading up on your tips. I'll be back as soon as I've looked into this. Again, thanks for your answer.